# Finding entire fluctuation in a dataset

Tags: mysql, sql, data-analysis

I have a table of historic data for a set of tanks in a MySQL database. I want to find fluctuations in the volume of tank contents of greater than 200 gallons/hour. My SQL statement thus far is:

```
SELECT t1.tankhistid as start, t2.tankhistid as end
FROM
    (SELECT * from tankhistory WHERE tankid = ? AND curtime BETWEEN ? AND ?) AS t1
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT * from tankhistory WHERE tankid = ? AND curtime BETWEEN ? AND ?) AS t2
    ON t1.tankid = t2.tankid AND t1.curtime < t2.curtime
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, t1.curtime, t2.curtime) < 1 AND ABS(t1.vol - t2.vol) > 200
ORDER BY t1.tankhistid, t2.tankhistid
```

In the code above, curtime is a timestamp at the time of inserting the record, tankhistid is the table integer primary key, tankid is the individual tank id, and vol is the volume reading.

This returns too many results since data is collected every 5 minutes and fluctuations could take hours (multiple rows with the same id in an end and then start column) , or just over 10 minutes (multiple rows with the same start or end id).  Example output:

```
7514576,7515478
7515232,7515478
7515314,7515478
7515396,7515478
7515478,7515560
7515478,7515642
7515478,7515724
```

Note that all of these rows should just be one: 7514576,7515724. The query takes 4 minutes for just one day of a tank's data, so any speed up would be great as well. I am guessing there is a way to take the current query and use it as a subquery, but I am not sure how to do the filtering.

Comment: You specify 200 gallons/hour and your readings are performed every 5 minutes.  Could this mean you simply need to list every sequential reading thats volume difference is greater than (200/12) gallons?

Comment: Well...in theory readings are taken every 5 minutes, but there is some variation in that due to software failure.

Comment: So, then is it possible to only display consecutive records where the rate of volume change exceeds 200 gallons/hr? i.e. 200/(60/(timestamp1-timestamp2))